# Convert 59 to octal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-systems

I'm reading [Discrete Mathematics by Kevin Ferland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618415386) and I'm stuck with exercise `33` of `Chapter 0`: Write the octal number equivalent of `59`.

I'm following this procedure:

```
59/8 | 3
 7/8 | ??
```

By using an online calculator, the result should be `73`, however how can the reminder of `7/8` be `7`?

Comment: $$7=8\cdot0+7$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide $7$ by $8$ you get an integer quotient of $0$ and a remainder of $7$: $7=0\cdot8+7$. This is the unique representation of $7$ in the form $8q+r$, where $q$ and $r$ are integers, and $0\le r<8$.

Answer (score 2):

Determining the remainder here given by $\frac 78$ is inappropriate.

What we *do* have is that $\dfrac{59}8 = 7$ with a remainder $3$.

So $$\underbrace{59_{10}}_{59} \underbrace{=}_{=} \underbrace{\color{blue}{\bf 7}\times 8^1}_{56} \underbrace{+}_{+}\underbrace{\color{red}{\bf 3}\times 8^0}_{3}= \color{blue}{\bf 7}\color{red}{\bf3}_{8}$$

Comment: Nice color coding +1

Answer (score 0):

$59=64-5=8^2-5=10_8^2-5=100_8-5_8=73_8$ , since $5+3=7+1=8=10_8$.

Answer (score 0):

59 = 7 * 8^1 + 3 * 8^0
Therefore 59 in base 10 is 73 in base 8